# linuxdcpp unable to share the right folder in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i just installed dc++ on ubuntu, but all the time it is selecting my entire home folder for file share even when i navigate through the UI to the folder i want to upload.

checked many ubuntu forums but couldn't find a precise workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters I think this question belongs at AskUbuntu.
Nevertheless, in your home folder there is a folder called `.dc++`, in it you can find a file named `DCPlusPlus.xml`. It is the main settings file of DC++

You should easily find the share directory listed there, simply change it and restart linuxdpp.